# Open streaming video in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, streaming, xdg-open

I am trying to stream baseball from the First Row Sports website running Chrome in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  The URL is http://firstrowca.eu/watch/15570/1/watch-mlb-network.html.

I followed a tutorial for streaming torrents on Ubuntu (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4kboJXrsY8) then clicked the "After install click here to launch stream" which opens this URL in Chrome:

```
st://A1YCgpwEdU4DTgaCoAHIgBbEgafIQcoHDpKJkb1RZuWCihcEQkI0VYphAIpBB2RlZmF1bHSKoh5TcG9ydHMsIEdlbmVyYWwsIFdvcmxkV2lkZSBGdW4=
```

Chrome gives me the pop-up:

```
External Protocol Request

Google Chrome needs to launch an external application to handle st: links.  The link requested is st://.....

The following application will be launched if you accept this request:

xdg-open
```

Clicking the "Launch Application" button does nothing.

I also tried running this from the command line:

```
xdg-open st://A1YCgpwEdU4DTgaCoAHIgBbEgafIQcoHDpKJkb1RZuWCihcEQkI0VYphAIpBB2RlZmF1bHSKoh5TcG9ydHMsIEdlbmVyYWwsIFdvcmxkV2lkZSBGdW4=
```

And get this error:

```
gvfs-open: st://A1YCgpwEdU4DTgaCoAHIgBbEgafIQcoHDpKJkb1RZuWCihcEQkI0VYphAIpBB2RlZmF1bHSKoh5TcG9ydHMsIEdlbmVyYWwsIFdvcmxkV2lkZSBGdW4=: error opening location: The specified location is not supported.
```

How can I get streaming to work?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you followed the wrong video-guide. The software you installed can't handle the `st://` URLs used by that streaming site you indicate.

You'd probably need to follow the site guide, but using WINE on Ubuntu:

http://firstrowca.eu/streamtorrent.html

I have not used any of this personally, but while giving it a quick web search have seen that several people were successful using it under WINE. Maybe also in combination with VLC.